# How to draw Pollard Rho figure like the attached figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw Pollard Rho figure like the figure above, using TikZ?

[image]

In the figure there should be arrows from `x_5` to `x_6` etc. Also there should be a starting point `x_4`.

Comment: https://github.com/mtrimoska/Tikz_figures_from_my_Thesis/blob/main/6_1/6_1.tex